# How to pass twilio API key's to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble passing my API keys from my .env file to my controller. when i currently run my rails app i get an action control error wtih 'Account SID and auth token are required'

```
    twilio_sid = ENV["ACCOUNT_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["AUTH_TOKEN"]

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token
```

Does anyone know how to pass my API key from the .env folder to my controller? I suspect that I need to make a file in my initialize folder but have not found any documentation of what to put there. thanks.

Comment: Check out the dotenv gem https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv.

Comment: @JeremyE I restarted my local rails server and that worked for me. Hope this helps